# Why do I not get a match using preg_match

Tags: php

I'm trying to extract the values Navn, Telefon, E-postadresse and Adresse from a text file. The structure in the text file comes from a converted pdf file, thus the blank lines between the lines with text. I'm using php preg_match_all to extract the values. The loop only extracts the first value which is the Navn value. I don't get a hit on the rest. Can anyone point me in the right direction on this?
Here is the text file content:

```
    Kontaktperson:

    Navn: Johan Wathne

    Telefon: 99566530

    99566530

    E-postadresse: johancqöhwheno
```

My PHP code looks like this where the variable $fileContent contains the text above:

```
if (preg_match('/Kontaktperson:\s*(.*?)\n\n/ms', $fileContent, $matches)) {
    $kontaktpersonSection = trim($matches[1]);

    // Extract Tiltakshaver fields
    if (preg_match_all('/(Navn|Telefon|E-postadresse|Adresse):\s*([^\n]+)\s*(?:\n\n|$)/', $kontaktpersonSection, $kontaktMatches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
        $kontaktpersonInfo = "Kontaktperson\n";
        $currentkontakt = "";
        foreach ($kontaktMatches as $kontaktMatch) {
            if ($kontaktMatch[1] === "Navn") {
                $currentkontakt = "Navn";
                $kontaktValue = $kontaktMatch[2];
                $kontaktpersonInfo .= "$currentkontakt: $kontaktValue\n";
            } elseif ($kontaktMatch[1] === "Telefon") {
                $currentkontakt = "Telefon";
                $kontaktValue = explode("\n", $kontaktMatch[2])[0];
                $kontaktpersonInfo .= "$currentkontakt: $kontaktValue\n";
            } elseif ($kontaktMatch[1] === "E-postadresse") {
                $currentkontakt = "E-postadresse";
                $kontaktValue = $kontaktMatch[2];
                $kontaktpersonInfo .= "$currentkontakt: $kontaktValue\n";
            } elseif ($kontaktMatch[1] === "Adresse") {
                $currentkontakt = "Adresse";
                $kontaktValue = $kontaktMatch[2];
                $kontaktpersonInfo .= "$currentkontakt: $kontaktValue\n";
            }
        }
        $extractedInfo .= $kontaktpersonInfo;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Dumping `$kontaktMatches` could help

Comment: It seems to me like there might be a special character issue with the "E-postadresse" value. Check if there are any non-standard characters or encoding differences that might be causing the regular expression to fail.

Comment: `$kontaktpersonSection` [doesn't contain what you want](https://regex101.com/r/xgUxHx/1), as it stops just before `Telefon`. You'll only match `Navm:`.

Comment: For future steps, it would be good to set up XDebug and run your code slowly, looking at what your variables contain. If you can't do that, then dump your variables to a log file or print them with `var_export()` or `var_dump()`. Also, play around with your regular expression on regex101.com with the correct PCRE version and this will help you find what's going wrong.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to regex101.com. I'm not familiar with that tool, but I guess I'll figure out how to use it.

Comment: It may be good to give us a bit more of the file, so that we can help you correct your first regular expression to extract the contact fields you want. By the way, are they optional? Are they always in the same order? What helps you figure out the end of a contact field? Are there many of them in the PDF?

Comment: The `/m` (multiline) modifier treats every line as a single subject to search. `/s` (dotall) makes dot and `\s` to match newlines. I´d drop the multiline modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, your first regular expression isn't
capturing all what you want, leading to missing fields below.

I would change your regular expression to this:

```
/
# Opening of contact person:
Kontaktperson:
\s*   # Ignore spaces
(.*?) # Capture all the fields.
# It should end with one of these:
(?: # Non-capturing group
  $ # End of file
  | # or
  \n{3} # 3 new lines
  | # or
  \n(?=Kontaktperson:) # A new line followed by Kontaktperson:
)
/gsx
```

See it in action with the help: https://regex101.com/r/YJMYhJ/1

I don't know what helps you find the end of the contact person section
but I assume it could be:

- The end of the file : `$` (don't use the `m` flag if not `$` matches
  the end of a line)
- At least 3 new lines (as you already had 2 lines between fields).
- A new line followed by a new opening contact person section. Here I
  use a positive lookahead to avoid "eating" the `Kontaktperson:` text
  so that we can match the next occurences.

I used the `x` flag so that you can put comments in your pattern.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I resolved this problem by editing my pattern to this: $pattern = '/Kontaktperson:\s*(.*?)(?=(?:\n{3}|(?=\nKontaktperson:)))/s'

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a regex if your input is well structured.

You can use

`$blob = explode("\n", $fileContent);`

to break $fileContent into an array, then use `strpos()` and `substr()` to extract everything to the right of the colon for the appropriate lines.